# USB 3.0 hard drive in usb 3 port only recognized as usb 2

Tags: windows-8.1, external-hard-drive, usb-storage, pci-express, usb-3

Today, I bought a Sabrent CP-4PTU USB 3.0 PCI Express Controller. I installed the latest software from the website, and after a reboot, I plugged in a USB 3.0 hard drive into the controller, and the computer told me that the hard drive could perform better if plugged into a superspeed USB port even though it was plugged in one. I tried with the other three ports with the same result. The box claims compatibility with Windows XP, Vista, and 7, but not 8 or 8.1. I have an MS-7390 Motherboard, a Geforce GTX 460 v2 GPU, and an AMD Athlon X2 Dual Core 5600+ CPU. How could I fix the problem?

[image: Device Manager]

Comment: Please post a screenshot of Device Manager in “By connection” view, _expanded to your USB hard drive_.

Comment: @DanielB I have added the screenshot.

Comment: Are you sure the hdd is a USB 3 device because the picture clearly indicates that a USB 2.0 hub is connected to your USB 3.0 device

Comment: @Ramhound http://imgur.com/0FNhbis

Comment: Did you plug in the power connection on your USB controller card?

Comment: Yes @DanielB, but I am not sure of a proper connection. How do I test?

Comment: Try a different USB 3 device and/or follow the instructions

Comment: @Ramhound I don't have one...

Comment: @DanielB I bet it's because it wasn't powered properly now.

Comment: I found various possible issues, some relating to power (like broken soldered connections), but nothing seems to fit the bill here. VIA USB 3.0 controllers (and drivers) seem to be quite error-prone. It’ll probably be best if you get another card, e.g. with a NEC chipset.

Comment: WD cable may be the culprit. Try to change it.

Comment: @Kasun the cable works fine on my laptop's usb 3 port.

Comment: Try to boot from Ubuntu live and just see what happens. This is just to check hardware is problem or driver problem. http://askubuntu.com/questions/217676/how-do-i-find-out-whether-my-system-has-usb-3-0-ports

Answer (score -3):

Buy Compatible stuff. The same thing will likely happen if you buy a fancy keyboard or mouse that is last generation and does not explicitly say it's compatible with WIN8.1, or check the manufacturers website to see if they have an update to make it compatible with WIN8.1.
I had this issue once with a webcam going from Vista to 7. I had to find a generic driver and eventually got it to work but I would have saved myself a lot of time and money if I had just gotten a new cam, which I did as the old one looked crappy anyways.
This is Why I've not upgraded to 8. I have a fancy KB and Mouse and Headset that are not explicitly listed as being compatible.
The other option is to plug the drive into your routers usb3 port.
For example I have a 3TB WD USB3 drive plugged into my nighthawk and it works swimmingly.

Comment: I’m sorry, but how is this an answer? It’s USB, there are standard classes like mass storage. Unless the device is _broken_, it will work with any system that supports USB mass storage. Which is just about any modern operating system.

Comment: Yes that is correct but some devices don't implement the "standard" properly and need proprietary vendor+os specific drivers to use those usb3 devices.